# Force Resharper to open designer when navigating with CTRL+SHIFT+T

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, resharper, resharper-5.0

When I press CTRL+SHIFT+T dialog for file search pops up, I find file I'm interested in, and when I press Enter - if file is .resx or .dbml - it's opens in text editor. Can I force Resharper to open file in whatever editor is used by default (same as when I double click on file in Solution Explorer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/290802;jsessionid=E15C9C4F0A9AB521994CAEFE5DC28B6A?tstart=0